# Can't link conan generated package

Tags: cmake, conan

I'm trying to dive into conan package management. I run local conan server, built and upload the most simple example package ["say"](https://github.com/conan-io/examples2/tree/main/examples/conanfile/layout/conanfile_in_subfolder).

Now I try to use the package (say/1.0).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <say.h>

int main() {
    say();
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(SayTest)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

include(conan_toolchain.cmake)
find_package(say)

add_executable(SayTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SayTest say::say)
```

All seems correct but I get:

```
...
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SayTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable SayTest
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/SayTest.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9): undefined reference to `say()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SayTest.dir/build.make:97: SayTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/SayTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

The problem is that linker doesn't recieve "-l" option:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/SayTest.dir/main.cpp.o -o SayTest -L/home/.conan2/p/b/say3dc85d2026593/p/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/home/.conan2/p/b/say3dc85d2026593/p/lib
```

The stuff begins to work if I add "say" name to target_link_libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(SayTest say::say say)
```

Question: Why I have to explicitly add library name? Is there a way to do it automatically? For instance, if I use Qt packages I don't need to do that.

Comment: CMake toolchain cannot be included like ``include(conan_toolchain.cmake)``. They have to be passed in command line like ``-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake``, the behavior is not the same in both cases. Also the build type shouldn't be hardcoded like ``set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)``, but defined externally. For both cases, using CMake presets is a convenient way.

Comment: It seems that you are missing the ``target_link_libraries(mytarget PUBLIC say::say)``, the "PUBLIC" argument in the middle is necessary

Comment: @drodri I tried you recipie. But nothing changed.
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
and
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(SayTest)
find_package(say)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC say::say)

Comment: Your `say` recipe is missing a `package_info()` method where you should populate `cpp_info.libs` (basically `self.cpp_info.libs = ["say"]`) so that `CMakeDeps` can know what are the libs to add to this `say::say` target.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes Yes, this is the solution! Thanks!